# How to build jquery rotate gallery going back and forward?

Tags: jquery, html

So I have this gallery in Jquery that allows me to see images but only going forward. What I need is when the user clicks the right side of the image it moves to the next image, but when the user clicks the left side of the image it moves to the previous image.

This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Rita Carneiro</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,500,600,700,800,900&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="close1">
            <img src="images/millions_1.jpg"  id="ImgGallery1" onclick="rotateGalleryOne()">
            <div class="closeInPortrait1">
                <div id="description1">
                    <p>Millions is a collaboration with photographer Gustavo Nina. It focuses on a group of people in a music festival.
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    2018
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </script>
        var counterOne = 0,
                galleryOne = ["images/millions_2.jpg", "images/millions_3.jpg", "images/millions_4.jpg", "images/millions_5.jpg", "images/millions_6.jpg", "images/millions_7.jpg", "images/millions_9.jpg", "images/millions_12.jpg", "images/millions_13.jpg", "images/millions_1.jpg"],
                rotateGalleryOne = function () {
                    document.getElementById("ImgGallery1").src = galleryOne[counterOne];
                    counterOne++;
                    if (counterOne >= galleryOne.length) {
                        counterOne = 0;
                    }
            };
        <script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any solutions to this will be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I'd recommend modifying your `DOM` to have two controls, one for going backward and one for going forward. Positioning those over the image with CSS should be doable, allowing for clicks on the `left` side of the image to go in reverse, and the `right` side of the image to go forward.

```js
 var counterOne = 0,
   galleryOne = ["https://images.pexels.com/photos/991422/pexels-photo-991422.jpeg", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1054198/pexels-photo-1054198.jpeg", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1054219/pexels-photo-1054219.jpeg", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1054201/pexels-photo-1054201.jpeg"],
   rotateGalleryOne = function(dir) {
    if(dir == 'back'){
     counterOne--;
     if (counterOne < 0) {
      counterOne = galleryOne.length-1;
     }
    } else {
     counterOne++;
     if (counterOne >= galleryOne.length) {
      counterOne = 0;
     }
    }
    document.getElementById("ImgGallery1").src = galleryOne[counterOne];
  };
```

```css
 img {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .close1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
 .gallery-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
 }
 .gallery-nav {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  top: 0;
 }
 .gallery-nav.nav-left {
  left: 0;
 }
 .gallery-nav.nav-right {
  right: 0;
 }
 .gallery-nav span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="close1">
 <div class="gallery-box">
  <div class="gallery-nav nav-left" onclick="rotateGalleryOne('back')">
   <span><</span>
  </div>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/991422/pexels-photo-991422.jpeg" id="ImgGallery1">
  <div class="gallery-nav nav-right" onclick="rotateGalleryOne('forward')">
   <span>></span>
  </div>
  <div id="description1">
   <p>Millions is a collaboration with photographer Gustavo Nina. It focuses on a group of people in a music festival.
   <br>
   <br>
   2018
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```